# How can I write formula of the t distribution?

Tags: equations

[image]

I tried to write this formula but ı could not. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please add you attempt, and describe where you are stuck.

Comment: @downvoters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

To improve the readability (if not the intelligibility) of the formula of the pdf of a central Student-t distribution, you may want to employ inline-fraction notation instead of `\frac`-notation.

Both approaches are illustrated in the following screenshot and associated LaTeX code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'align*' environment
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for '\mathbb' macro
\begin{document}
\noindent
The probability density function of a central Student-$t$ distribution is given by
\begin{align*}
f(t,\nu) 
&= \frac{\Gamma\bigl(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\bigr)}{%
   \sqrt{\nu\pi}\,\Gamma\bigl(\frac{\nu}{2}\bigr)}
   \biggl(1+\frac{t^2}{\nu}\biggr)^{\!\!-(\frac{\nu+1}{2})} \\[\jot]
&= \frac{\Gamma((\nu+1)/2)}{%
   \sqrt{\nu\pi}\,\Gamma(\nu/2)}
   {(1+t^2\!/\nu)}^{\!-(\nu+1)/2} 
\end{align*}
with $\nu>0$, $t\in\mathbb{C}$, and $t\ne\sqrt{\nu}\,i$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that kind of "simple" situation, just try first to use the free version of MathPix which finds :

```
$f(t)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\nu \pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)}\left(1+\frac{t^{2}}{\nu}\right)^{-\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)}$
```

Comment: The overall "look" of this formula would be greatly enhanced by the insertion of `\,` (thinspace) after `\sqrt{\nu \pi}`.

Comment: @Mico The formula has been directly made by the tool MathPix.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't feel very comfortable with LaTeX syntax, you can help yourself by breaking it down into smaller parts and testing them separately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

 \def\A{\Gamma\left( \frac{\nu + 1}{2} \right)}
% $\A$ uncomment for testing

\def\B{\sqrt{\nu\pi} \Gamma\left( \frac{\nu}{2} \right)}
% $\B$

 \def\C{1+\frac{t^2}{\nu}}
% $\C$

 \def\D{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}
% $\D$
 
\[  f(t)=\frac{\A}{\B}\left(\C\right)^{\D}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I dod not downvote. You should not encourage User to use `\def` they'll end up hurting themself

Comment: I also didn't downvote. That said, the big gap between `\Gamma` and the opening parenthesis, in your `\A` and `\B` terms, is just awful from a typographic perspective.

Comment: @daleif I agree with your remarks. I just wanted to illustrate Descartes' second precept: to divide each of the difficulties I would examine, into as many intrigues as possible, and which would be necessary to better resolve them. The \def have no place in the final document and are only used for debugging.

Comment: @Mico : I agree entirely with you, but my goal is not to present a perfect typography but to overcome the difficulties that some may have in developing the edition of a complex formula.

Comment: @gigiair - I don't perceive a contradiction or conflict between (a) constructing a longer formula as a composite of simpler macros and (b) succeeding in getting the typographic style elements right.

Comment: @Mico The PO asked "I tried to write this formula but I couldn't." He did not mention the difficulties he encountered. Maybe the complexity, maybe the spacing, or maybe yet another cause. I assumed it was the complexity.

Comment: My apologies for not being clearer in my earlier comment. My point was that reducing the complexity of a task doesn't mean one has to introduce other typographic issues (such as substandard spacing).

Comment: @downvoters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: @downvoters This code may just be tentative to expand on the formula.
The final formula is established by replacing the macros with their value. You can keep it as is by putting the code in a block so that the \def 's are local. I maintain that for a beginner the technique can help and I have applied it to myself.